# problem with repeated sensor values when writing to csv file

Tags: android, performance, android-sensors

I have an android app that gets data from the acceleration sensor and from rotation vector sensor at frequency of 100hz. It also gets the location from GPS every 1 second. The app does some calculations on the collected data on a timer every 10ms. and stores results on a csv file and uploads the file to firebase every 3 minutes.

The problem is that there are many consecutive repeated values on the resulting csv file even though the location listener runs on a separate thread and the sensors listener runs on a separate thread, and also writing to file and uploading to Firebase are done asynchronously.

The iOS version of the app is written natively using swift with approximately the same procedure but does not have this issue.

```java
mSensorThread = new HandlerThread("Sensor thread", Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
mSensorThread.start();
Handler mSensorHandler = new Handler(mSensorThread.getLooper());

mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, 10000,9000,mSensorHandler);
mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mRotationVector, 10000,9000, mSensorHandler);
```

```java
mLocationThread = new HandlerThread("Location thread", Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
mLocationThread.start();
Looper looper = mLocationThread.getLooper();

LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates (mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this, looper).addStatusListener(new PendingResult.StatusListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(Status status) {
        startRecording();
    }
});
```

```java
t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // some calculations on sensors data.
    }
}, 0, period);
```

```java
private void writeToCsvFileAndFirebase(final String data, final Date lastDate) {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // write the file and upload to firebase every 3 minuets.
            // this function is called from the scheduled timer.
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every `10ms` sounds problematic, while this part is even missing; I don't even understand why `10ms`, when the values only change every `100ms`. If you open/write/close a file there, this is doomed to fail; keeping the values in RAM and occasionally flushing them to file, might be less processing overhead.

I mean, just consider the processing time & asynchronous operation, which may cause the iterations to interfere each other. lowering the interval might be worth a try - or better use a [Semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) to prevent a possible race condition, independent from the interval; that `CSV` is a shared resource.

`Java` will always run a tad slower than `C++`. Using [JNI](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html) might be an option.

Comment: thank you for your answer. But many Android devices can give accelerometer and angles values at a rate up to 200hz and I made sure of that on my device. there is a complex algorithm that runs on the backend that needs very precise sensor data to come up with results, and on the specifications of the app, the rate should be 100hz. 
and how race conditions may cause repeated values?